# SQLCMD gives conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: t-sql, sqlcmd, invoke-sqlcmd

The important part of this question being the use of Sqlcmd.  Simply, I'm trying to figure out how to use date/time in my scripts and documentation is light on this.

I've tried several date formats, conversion and casting, etc.

Anyone have ideas?

```sql
-- I don't know how else to format this but as a string
:SETVAR CURRENT_DATE "2016-09-15T17:30:00"

PRINT CONVERT(DATETIME2,'${CURRENT_DATE}',106)
```

Gives the error:
`Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

**EDIT:**

I think it has something to do with sqlcmd and not the formatting.

This works:

```
PRINT CONVERT(DATETIME2,'2016-09-15T17:30:00', 106)
```

And this works:

```
PRINT CONVERT(DATETIME2,'2016-09-15T17:30:00', 126)
```

But using Setvar it does **not** work

```
:SETVAR CURRENT_DATE "2016-09-15T17:30:00"
PRINT CONVERT(DATETIME2,'${CURRENT_DATE}',126)
```

I also don't care what format the datetme is in, so I can change it if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm a fool.  Wrong kind of brackets:

```sql
:SETVAR CURRENT_DATE "2016-09-15T17:30:00"
PRINT CONVERT(DATETIME2,'$(CURRENT_DATE)',126)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong [`style`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles) parameter in your `convert` function.
For ISO8601 you should use 126, not 106 as you're doing now.

This should work:

```
:SETVAR CURRENT_DATE "2016-09-15T17:30:00"

PRINT CONVERT(DATETIME2,'${CURRENT_DATE}',126)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work for me.  Please see edits.  Thanks!